# Low resolution display for QR Codes

Tags: displays

I am looking to build an application that needs to display a QR code, and I want to minimize the cost of it.

I just need a preferably square display, capable of displaying a simple QR code with a short url, nothing more.

Can anyone recommend me something that is as cheap as possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objective may be resolved with a device known as an e-paper kit.

[image: e-paper kit]

The one in the image above is 154 pixels square, qualifying for your low-resolution requirement. There are other sizes on the market, other resolutions and a wide range of costs. The one in the image is priced less than US$10.00. It's uncertain what you consider to be low-cost.

You should be able to find that you can purchase a processor such as an Arduino or Pi or adapt your current source to the product you select.

Amazon sells a hat for a Pi at a bit higher cost than the above device:

[image: Amazon Pi Hat for e-paper]

Comment: I am searching for even more low cost, I think I have to take the pain of led matrix if I want it to be cheap. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If your QR code is small enough (64x64 pixels max, so version 11) you can use an OLED display driven by a SSH1106 or SSD 1136. They can be controlled over I2C or SPI and don't draw a lot of power. Biggest drawback is that most are a bit small, maximum QR code size is 14.7x14.7 mm.

They sell for about US$2.50